# Returning elements from a loop, one at a time

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a simple function to parse a .csv as follows

```
def grabber3(datafile):

with open(datafile, 'rb') as f:
    r =csv.DictReader(f)
    for line in r:
        del line['thisthing']
        print line
```

This print out each dict line correctly which is about 50 lines such as

```
{'NetworkStatus': '1', 'ID': '1469'}
{'NetworkStatus': '1', 'ID': '1470'}
etc etc
```

However I i want to return this when the function is called so I change the print statement to return as

```
def grabber3(datafile):

with open(datafile, 'rb') as f:
    r =csv.DictReader(f)
    for line in r:
        del line['thisthing']
    return line
```

but it only returns the first line

```
{'NetworkStatus': '1', 'ID': '1469'}
```

How do I return each line of the loop/all of the dict lines instead of just the first one?

Comment: first, you need to fix your tabs. the only way that's happening is if `return ` is part of the `for line...` block.

Comment: Correct the indentation in you function definitions to make it readable and understandable. It seems that in your second function definition you should append lines to some list and return a list of dictionaries.

Comment: or, what you really want, is a map of `ID` to `NetworkStatus`

Comment: In your current edit, the code would return the last line and not the first. I think your `del` and `return` are the same indentation level when you observe the first line being returned.

Comment: fixed indent to make more sense in question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An efficient way of doing this is to use `yield`:

```
def grabber3(datafile):
    with open(datafile, 'rb') as f:
        r =csv.DictReader(f)
        for line in r:
            del line['thisthing']
            yield line
```

And then in the code that calls this function, you can do:

```
dict_generator = grabber3(a_file)
```

And then iterate through this `dict_generator` as:

```
for a_dict in dict_generator:
    print a_dict
```

More on `yield` and generators here:

1. https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators
2. [What does the "yield" keyword do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do-in-python)

Comment: This worked just as I needed .Thanks. been away from python world awhile. Did not realize yield